# How to configure Geoserver Geowebcache to use custom projection?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I'm running Geoserver 2.3.2 with integrated GWC on my Linux computer on Tomcat. I created a custom gridset via Geoserver GUI, which I want to use for seeding, however I can't see it in grid sets combobox on gwc page.

I've read something about geowebcache.xml, but I can't find it in the directory structure neither. There is also no gwc dir in data-dir. Do I have to create these manually?

Also, when I try to seed the layer with the default epsg:4326 gridset, the task seems not to start running. The page is reloaded but no tiles are generated.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: check the log file and tell us what you see there (you may need to turn up the logging level)

Comment: Seems I'm done :-/ Getting an error everytime I try to access Tile Layers from the Geoserver menu. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GeoServerTileLayerInfo 'LayerInfoImpl--38800bb0:13ed0d3790c:-7d1b' does not exist.

Comment: Hi, I can't see anything related to GWC in geoserver log file. It is set to GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING level. I've created gwc folder in data-dir manually and set write permissions, however the task still does not start seeding.